# Add a bookmark if there is none in this position. (AppScript)

Tags: javascript, google-docs

Part of my script needs to add a bookmark to every H2 paragraph in a google document, save it's text content and the bookmark's url to use later.

The problem is that each time the script runs it creates more and more bookmarks and I can't manage to get the bookmark url to save.

```
//////////////

var doc = DocumentApp.openById('your document ID here');
var body = doc.getBody();
// Define the search parameters.
var searchType = DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH;
var searchHeading = DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2;
var searchResult = null;
var headingsList = [];
var urlList = [];
 

// Search until the paragraph is found.
while (searchResult = body.findElement(searchType, searchResult)) {
    var par = searchResult.getElement().asParagraph();
    if (par.getHeading() == searchHeading) {
        headingsList.push(par.getText());
    doc.addBookmark(doc.newPosition(par, 0));
    }
}
```

// This is the part of the code I managed to write, it works for creating the bookmarks (albeit multiple ones on top of each other) and it successfully saves the header text to an array.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get the URL, you could try getting it by retrieving the URL from the file itself, this would work as currently the [`Bookmark Class`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/bookmark) does not have any method that you can use like `getUrl`. Try using this code with a slight modification:

```
function BookmarkUrltest() {
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument(); // modify this to OpenbyId if needed.
var body = doc.getBody();
// Define the search parameters.
var searchType = DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH;
var searchHeading = DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2;
var searchResult = null;
var headingsList = [];
var urlList = [];
 

// Search until the paragraph is found.
while (searchResult = body.findElement(searchType, searchResult)) {
    var par = searchResult.getElement().asParagraph();
    if (par.getHeading() == searchHeading) {
        headingsList.push(par.getText());
    var burl = doc.addBookmark(doc.newPosition(par, 0));
    let bourl = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId()).getUrl().replace("?usp=drivesdk", "#bookmark=" + burl.getId());
    Logger.log(bourl);
    }
}
}
```

This code should retrieve the bookmark URL.

Comment: Thank you, I already managed to do get to very similar solution.
The issue is that the code still creates a new bookmark each time it runs and I want it to check if a bookmark already exists in this place and only create a new one if it doesn't.